# How to assign variable instead of integer

Tags: php

Hi im new to php and trying to explore! Im having a problem inserting my variable to my code. Heres my variables

```
 $jun = mysql_query("SELECT count(*) from tbl_users where MonthCreated = 'June' and YearCreated = '2016';");
 $jul = mysql_query("SELECT count(*) from tbl_users where MonthCreated = 'July' and YearCreated = '2016';");
 $aug = mysql_query("SELECT count(*) from tbl_users where MonthCreated = 'August' and YearCreated = '2016';");
 $sep = mysql_query("SELECT count(*) from tbl_users where MonthCreated = 'September' and YearCreated = '2016';");
 $oct = mysql_query("SELECT count(*) from tbl_users where MonthCreated = 'October' and YearCreated = '2016';");
 $nov = mysql_query("SELECT count(*) from tbl_users where MonthCreated = 'November' and YearCreated = '2016';");
 $dec = mysql_query("SELECT count(*) from tbl_users where MonthCreated = 'December' and YearCreated = '2016';");
```

And here is where im trying to put it:

```
$(function () {
    $('#container').highcharts({
    title: {
        text: 'Monthly Average Requests',
        x: -20 //center
    },
    subtitle: {
        text: 'Source: Barangay Harapin ang Bukas',
        x: -20
    },
    xAxis: {
        categories: ['Jan', 'Feb', 'Mar', 'Apr', 'May', 'Jun',
            'Jul', 'Aug', 'Sep', 'Oct', 'Nov', 'Dec']
    },
    yAxis: {
        title: {
            text: 'Volume'
        },
        plotLines: [{
            value: 0,
            width: 1,
            color: '#808080'
        }]
    },
    tooltip: {
        valueSuffix: '' //suffix *C
    },
    legend: {
        layout: 'vertical',
        align: 'right',
        verticalAlign: 'middle',
        borderWidth: 0
    },
    series: [{
        name: 'Complaints',
        data: [7.0, 6.9, 9.5, 14.5, 18.2, 21.5, 25.2, 26.5, 23.3, 18.3, 13.9,20]
    }, {
        name: 'Services',
        data: [-0.2, 0.8, 5.7, 11.3, 17.0, 22.0, 24.8, 24.1, 20.1, 14.1, 8.6, 2.5]
    }, {
        name: 'Registered Constituents',
```

Here exactly is where im tyring to put my variables. Cant figure this out.

```
    data: [$jul,$aug]

    }]
});
});
```

Comment: You need to fetch the result object. Also `$jul` is not PHP unless you enter the PHP block and output it `<?php echo $jul; ?>`.

Answer (score 0):

```
$result = mysql_query("SELECT count(*) as count from tbl_users where MonthCreated = 'June' and YearCreated = '2016';");
$row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result);
$jun = $row['count'];


$result = mysql_query("SELECT count(*) as count from tbl_users where MonthCreated = 'July' and YearCreated = '2016';");
$row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result);
$jul = $row['count'];

$result = mysql_query("SELECT count(*) as count from tbl_users where MonthCreated = 'August' and YearCreated = '2016';");
$row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result);
$aug = $row['count'];

$result = mysql_query("SELECT count(*) as count from tbl_users where MonthCreated = 'September' and YearCreated = '2016';");
$row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result);
$sep = $row['count'];


$result = mysql_query("SELECT count(*) as count from tbl_users where MonthCreated = 'October' and YearCreated = '2016';");
$row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result);
$oct = $row['count'];


$result = mysql_query("SELECT count(*) as count from tbl_users where MonthCreated = 'November' and YearCreated = '2016';");
$row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result);
$nov = $row['count'];


$result = mysql_query("SELECT count(*) as count from tbl_users where MonthCreated = 'December' and YearCreated = '2016';");
$row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result);
$dec = $row['count'];
```

You need to retrieve the value of count from each object like I have give in my solution

Comment: This is not the efficient way to handle this problem, but as you are new to PHP, so I have solved this problem in simple procedural style  so that you could understand.

Answer (score 0):

As @aman said You need to execute query.

You can group Your's results in one query instead of call Db multiple times

```
SELECT MonthCreated, count(id) AS result 
FROM tbl_users 
WHERE YearCreated = '2016'
GROUP BY MonthCreated
```

result should be looks like:

```
[
    'June' => 11
    'July' => 34
    'August' => 56
];
```

If You want to set those data there 2 ways:

1) if you print resposne js just paste data inline as @chris85 said:

```
data: [<?php echo $jul, $aug ?>]
```

but it's ugly solution, allowed only when You learn.

2) Load default js (chart I suppose) and call data by Ajax. Then in PHP You will return Json encoded data. Example thread [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30928840/chart-js-getting-data-from-database-using-mysql-and-php)

Please use dedicated library like [ADODB](http://adodb.org/dokuwiki/doku.php), to prevent ie. SQL Injection.
It will more comforrtable, as You will learn more.

Please don't use camelCase in column names.

Comment: Hi Jacek and Aman! Thank you for the reply I tried following as suggested: 

`$sql3 = mysql_query("SELECT count(*) from tbl_users where MonthCreated = 'August' and YearCreated = '2016';");
$row3 = mysql_fetch_assoc($sql3);
$aug = $row3['count'];`

I have 2 records in august and tried outputting it but no value appears

`data: [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,<?php echo $aug ?>]`
Thank you for your advices and guidance

Comment: First thing, check [mysql_query](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-query.php) doc page. You wil see it's deprecated. Use mysql**i** functions (for You it will by only 'i' at the end of mylsq(and rest)). Second, You can check varabile type using `var_dump()` function. `mysqli_fetch_assoc` returns associative array, so you check fields keys using `var_dump()` and print them using ie. `$aug['count(*)']`, or if You will use alias in query `SELECT count(*) AS result`, print `echo $aug['result']`