# Pushing json encoded php into chart.js

Tags: php, json, mysqli

I am trying to push json encoded form my database select into chart.js data set but im not sure how to go about it without over engineering it.

Here is a simple select of scores from its retrospective table:

```
if($teamData == 0){
  $allTeams = 'All';
} else{
$sql = "SELECT * FROM compScore WHERE memberId = 1";
$result = $conn->query($sql);


  if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
      while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
          $jsonScores = json_encode($row, JSON_PRETTY_PRINT);
    }
  }
}
header('Content-type: application/json');
echo $jsonScores;
```

the output of this is:

```
{ "id": "1", "score1": "2", "score2": "3", "score3": "5", "score4": "4", "score5": "3", "score6": "2", "score7": "1", "score8": "3", "memberId": "1" }
```

I have one issue where it only fetches 1 record and I also want to exclude the field `memberId`

Even more so how do I push that result into:

```
  datasets : [
    {
      fillColor: "rgba(102,45,145,.1)",
      strokeColor: "rgba(102,45,145,1)",
      pointColor : "rgba(220,220,220,1)",
      pointStrokeColor : "#fff",

      data : [] // HERE IS WHERE THE DATA NEEDS TO GO
    }
```

Comment: first remove unnecessary elements from array. refer this link : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4466159/delete-element-from-multidimensional-array-based-on-value

Comment: after that encode it in to json format and pass in to the js library portion.

Comment: @prakashtank im not sure how to pass it into the js lib, thats where I get a little stuck

Comment: @Dude : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30928840/chart-js-getting-data-from-database-using-mysql-and-php

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you should take a look into the json layout expected by charts.js.
https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/reference#dataparam
It requires a first level of cols and rows, where every column is described by an id, a label and a type.
The google documentation is pretty good, despite the format expected is kind of tedius.

And here a PHP example for populating the chart.

https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/php_example

Comment: Obviously this documentation is reference to Google charts, but I can easily translate this into chart.js? The example looks very similar.

Comment: Chart.js expects a very similar structure and is the only way it can fail so, attention to the json format and you should be fine.