# How many people are registering in the day of the week

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, mysql

Hi i want to make a chart for my project using chatjs. I have a users table and when user registered my site the registered time is datetime format like this `2018-03-02 10:35:25` . I want to make it with this chat **[DEMO](https://codepen.io/shadowman86/pen/EQMyzm)**

[image]

I need to write a php code to reveal the graph, like:

```
$months = array("Sunday", "Monday", "Tuesday", "Wednesday", "Thursday", "Friday", "Saturday");
$monthvalues = array();
foreach ($months as $month) {
    $monthvalues[$month] = 0;
}


 $result = mysqli_query($db,"SELECT registerTime, count(*) FROM users group by WEEKDAY(registerTime)") or die(mysql_error($db)); 
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result, MYSQL_NUM)) {
    $monthvalues[$row[0]] = (int)$row[1];
}
```

and i am printing it like this

```
// Data
var data = {
  labels: <?=json_encode($months);?>,
  datasets: [{
    label: "My Second dataset",
    fillColor: "rgba(151,187,205,0.2)",
    strokeColor: "rgba(151,187,205,1)",
    pointColor: "rgba(151,187,205,1)",
    pointStrokeColor: "#fff",
    pointHighlightFill: "#fff",
    pointHighlightStroke: "rgba(151,187,205,1)",
    data: <?=json_encode(array_values($monthvalues));?>
  }]
};
```

The query above gives me just one log report. I can not show it on the chart. I need an output that I can reflect on a weekly basis.

The problem is, I can not figure out how to do graphs with code. Could someone help me by giving an example in this matter please ?

the result should be `data: [28, 48, 40, 19, 86, 27, 90]` like this

january = 28, february = 48 , ...

Comment: Use [count](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_count_avg_sum.asp) function in your query

Comment: @jerome OK, but how do I do the days ? It should be with in one query, for example 28 user registered in january, 48 user registered in february... ect.

Comment: You can use mysql `MONTH()` method.

Comment: @MathieuDormeval the important think is how can i print it for all single day. MONTH() is ok .

Comment: As @jerome says, use count function or `DAY()` method

Comment: @MathieuDormeval I have added my new query can you check it for me please ?

Comment: @Azzo you could use [phpchartjs](https://github.com/halfpastfouram/PHPChartJS) to control your graph from PHP.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to return an array, you should use a GROUP BY, like this

```
SELECT COUNT(registerTime) as `count` FROM users WHERE DATE(registerTime) = CURDATE() GROUP BY MONTH(registerTime)
```

And you can add a month number in output to create labels

```
SELECT COUNT(registerTime) as `count`,MONTH(registerTime) as `month` FROM users WHERE DATE(registerTime) = CURDATE() GROUP BY MONTH(registerTime)
```

Comment: @alexander-demoichev So with this query I will get the total number of users for every day of the week.  for example 28 user registered in january, 48 user registered in february... ect. and  how can i result the outputs like this `data: [28, 48, 40, 19, 86, 27, 90]`

Comment: @Azzo i didnt have php within easy reach, what was returned in $row with query with GROUP BY?

Comment: your query only shows the number of people with a daily registered total user. I want to show seven days like : `28 user registered Sunday, 48 user registered Monday, 12 user registered Thuesday` . But your query showing just jurrent day.

Comment: i also updated my question now it shows me the result with your query but problem is it is showing just one day not showing current week registered users daily .

Comment: @Azzo look at your code, you groupping by DATE, it's not same thing that groupping by MONTH or DAY. Try to chage ur group on MONTH if u want to month groupping, or DAY if u want to group by single day

Comment: I want weekly with sum of day

Comment: so you need group by weeks?

Comment: I need How many user registered Sunday, How many user registered Monday, .... How many user registered Thuesday ect. For a chart graph. I said your query will show one day. Not all day in a week.

Comment: okay, try GROUP BY WEEKDAY(registerTime) - this will return count of registration by weekday index (0 - Sunday, 1 - Monday, etc... based on locale)

Comment: @alexander-demichec Please looke at the data result from this screenshot https://image.prntscr.com/image/8Ip2HtxOSZeXtablnm1Ghw.png and the graph looks like this https://image.prntscr.com/image/r9VoM6RjQcGF8CGEC3ZwUg.png . The point to note is only seven days a week, but output `data: [0,0,0,0,0,0,0,7,1,3]}]`  there are 10 day results :D

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/166100/discussion-between-alexander-demichev-and-azzo).